# Can I drop off carry-on luggage at Heathrow and pick it up later before flight?

Tags: layovers, lhr, hand-luggage, auh

I will have one carry one when I land on heathrow. I have 12+ hours stay. I intend to check the city out but I don't want to carry my carry on luggage with me. Is there a service where I can drop off the bag and pick it up before the flight? How much does it typical cost?

I have the same question for Abu Dhabi International airport as well. Thanks

Ok I I found [this link](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/store-luggage-airports-107069.html) that is helpful.

Comment: Depending on the flight and airline, and if you need your luggage before boarding the plane you *might* be able to check in early for the flight and check your bags then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the answer. Most airport has this facility where you can drop-off (store) your carry one and pick it up before flight. There is usually a fee for it.

[This links is for Heathrow Airport](http://www.heathrowairport.com/heathrow-airport-guide/services-and-facilities/left-baggage) 9 pounds/day

[This link is for Abu Dhabi Airport](http://www.abudhabiairport.ae/english/media/airport-service-centre_tcm13-4159.pdf) 20 durham/day